What is the ``physical interpretation" of $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} P^{(n)}_{i,i}$ of a Markov chain?
I'm trying to make sense of the limit theorem of Markov Chains that says
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\,\, P^{(n)}_{i,i}=\frac{1}{\sum_{n\geq 1}n f^{(n)}_{i,i}}$$.
The rigorous proof is standard sequences and series stuff, but I wanted to "see" why it is true.
The denominator of the RHS is the average value of return time to State-$i$, which can be thought of as $\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{N}{\text{number of times you return to} \,i\,\text{in the time}\,[0,N]}$, so its reciprocal is the "average number of returns per unit time".
What interpretation do we have of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\, P^{(n)}_{i,i}$ that makes the above equation intuitively obvious?

Do you consider the ergodic theorem to already be intuitive, or is this meant to be a stepping stone on the road there? (The idea that $\pi_i$ is the reciprocal of the mean return time from $i$ to $i$ is basically the ergodic theorem, and the LHS is at least some $\pi_i$ if it even exists, even though there might be several invariant distributions.)

Renewal Theory (tracking returns to state $j$) provides one interpretation. If $\mu$ denotes the denominator on the right, you have
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} {E^i\left[\#\{n\in\{1,2,\ldots, N\}: X_n=j \right]\over N}={1\over\mu}
$$
—frequency is the reciprocal of wavelength. The ratio on the left is
$$
{1\over N}\sum_{n=1}^N P^{(n)}_{i,j}.\qquad\qquad\qquad(\dagger)
$$
When the chain is aperiodic, the un-smoothed probabilities $P^{(n)}_{i,j}$ will themselves converge, and their limit will coincide with the limit of the ratio  ($\dagger$); namely, $1/\mu$.

Hi John, what does $E^i$ mean in the numerator of the limit you've written?

Expectation conditional on $X_0=i$.

I don't get why there's that expectation term. Since you are dividing by N, isn't it just the number of $k$ such that $X_k=j$ ?
